# Unable to boot into USB on HP Proliant DL160 G5

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, usb-boot

I recently purchased a used HP Proliant DL160 G5 to learn about servers and I am trying to install a fresh version of Windows Server via a USB installer.

Unfortunately, I am unable to boot into my USB despite my efforts to make sure the USB has the highest boot priority (refer to below image). All I see is a black screen with a blinking cursor when I try to boot into my USB.

[image]

**How do I boot into my USB on my server? I can confirm the USB has been set up correctly as I am able to boot into it from another server I have.**

Not sure if the following information is relevant to my issues booting into my USB but during the boot process, I am alerted with the following messages regarding the server's HP Smart Array P400 Controller:

```
Drive Array - Array Accelerator Battery/Capacitor Charge Low. Array Accelerator Posted-Write Cache is temporarily disabled.
```

However, despite these messages, I am still able to boot into the OS that is currently installed on the machine so I don't think it is the cause of my inability to boot into my USB.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the P400 error, have you checked the USB drive is bootable on another systems? Also is the server up to date with the latest SPP? You can also try booting it via iLO with the ISO file, that's actually what a lot of people do to build servers anyway, I've never built one with an actual physical USB myself.

Comment: You can try different USB-ports. Also, you can remove HDD and other media so server has no choice to boot from.

Comment: Usually it's the USB media - DL160 (even G5) does no have problemes booting from USB. Triple-Check that it's not UEFI or GPT.